# Is it possible to use image-set *and* multiple images at the same time?

Tags: css, sass

I'm currently going through with my team and finishing up our latest site, optimizing images and all that good stuff.

I've come across a small dilemma.
We have many background images. I wish to optimize them on supporting browsers using image-set, but I also love using [this technique](https://csswizardry.com/2016/10/improving-perceived-performance-with-multiple-background-images/) to improve perceived load times and for the nice added touch it gives. If I *do* have to choose, of course I'll go for the optimization.

**So**, my question to you all is this:
Can I use image-set as one of multiple backgrounds? If so, can you provide a working example? I gave it a go, but the browser rejected the code completely and so I just got the strikeouts in the inspector.

Here is an example of my code (as I am working in liquid and would prefer to not have to translate this it to true CSS unless needed):

```
background: image-set(
  url("URL") 1x,
  url("URL") 2x,
  url("URL") 3x,
  url("URL") 4x,
) center / 100% auto no-repeat,
linear-gradient(to right, #564029 0%, #6c5a43 50%, #6c573c 75%, #5d472f 100%) center / 100% auto no-repeat,
#72573c;
```

Feel free to point out if I've just missed something in my code. If nothing else, I hope this serves as something for someone else to stumble upon.

As far as things I've looked into for reference:

- I've looked at [multiple background examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds)
- I've looked at [image-set examples](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-image-set/)
- I did a reasonable dive into Google to try and find an example of the two combined. I won't say I was surprised to find nothing.

Final note, I am aware that the -webkit- prefix is still necessary.

Comment: beware of the poor support that `image-set` has https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-image-set

Comment: I am aware of the support. Thank you for pointing it out, but I know how to use fallbacks and I am prepared to use them :)

Comment: you don't seem to have any fallback in this property but ok

Comment: I gave a code example. I did not wish to give the full verbose code that I will be using on the actual site for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Yes and that's fine, always use a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but as I said it **seemed** in this MCVE, and I only mentioned that because usually  the fallback is  in the same property ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a trailing comma after your last argument to `image-set()`.

Here's the code without the trailing comma after "4x":

```
background: image-set(
  url("URL") 1x,
  url("URL") 2x,
  url("URL") 3x,
  url("URL") 4x
) center / 100% auto no-repeat,
linear-gradient(to right, #564029 0%, #6c5a43 50%, #6c573c 75%, #5d472f 100%) center / 100% auto no-repeat,
#72573c;
```

Comment: *Facepalm* Thank you. It works now.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Probably because questions like this that are solved by a simple typo correction aren't much use to others looking for answers in the future. Leave the answer as a comment, and flag `should be closed... > off topic... > typo or unreproducible`. Disclaimer: I'm not one of the downvoters.

Comment: If you answer questions that should be closed, then you get down-votes even your answer is right. Do no answer questions that has issues to be closed.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation.